# Retornar valores de un array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy aprendiendo a programar, para poder resolver este ejercicio se me pide que retorne un nuevo array con los valores de al array de objetos de amigos. Busque informacion pero no logro comprender del todo o no me sale

```
  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {

  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.hobbies = hobbies;
  this.amigos = [{nombre: 'martin', edad: 31},{nombre: 'toni', edad: 33}];

  }

  var friends = []

  for(var i = 0; i < this.amigos.length; i++){
    friends.push(amigos[i])
  }

  return friends
```

Voy haciendo esto pero sigue sin salirme, tambien probe con map:

```
var friends = Persona.map(function(e){

    return e.amigos
})
  return friends
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que tu clase sea esta:

```
class Persona{
    constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos){
          this.nombre = nombre;
          this.edad = edad;
          this.hobbies = hobbies;
          this.amigos = [{nombre: 'martin', edad: 31},{nombre: 'toni', edad: 33}]
    }
}
```

y luego declares una instancia de la siguiente manera:

```
let instanciaDePersona = new Persona('Juan', 18, 'bailar');
```

puedes conseguir la lista de amigos de la siguiente forma:

```
let listaDeAmigos = instanciaDePersona.amigos;
```

y para imprimirlos harias lo siguiente:

```
console.log(listaDeAmigos);

// o con un ciclo
listaDeAmigos.forEach((amigoActual)=>{
    console.log(amigoActual);
});
```

**EDIT:**

tu archivo `app.js` deberia verse de la siguente manera:

```
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
    this.amigos = [{ nombre: 'martin', edad: 31 }, { nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 }]
  }
}

let instanciaDePersona = new Persona('Juan', 18, 'bailar');

let listaDeAmigos = instanciaDePersona.amigos;

listaDeAmigos.forEach((amigoActual) => {
  console.log(amigoActual.nombre);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español Francisco!

Te recomiendo siempre a la hora de preguntar poner suficiente código para entender que es lo qué estás haciendo, en este caso veo que estás haciendo una clase pero no pones la definición de la clase lo cual vuelve muy confuso lo qué haces luego del constructor, es decir, ese `return` que haces al final de quién es? Además podrías compartir también un breve código con lo que estás haciendo las pruebas para descartar cualquier error de debugeo que pudieses estar cometiendo.

Ahora, viendo tu código tienes un par de problemas:

1. Como dije anteriormente estas haciendo un `return` en la clase que anda ahí flotando, no sé si lo que querías era un método que te extraiga los amigos (en este caso sería un `getter` ya que te devuelve una propiedad de tu objeto).
2. Cuando tratas de llenar el array de `friends` con el `push()` haces referencia a `amigos` lo cuál no está definido, tienes que referenciarlo por medio de `this` ya que estás trabajando con tu clase.
3. Si estás usando tu constructor para inicializar amigos creo que deberías de utilizar el parámetro de entrada, como con los demás parámetros.

Tomando esto en cuenta tu código y haciendo suposiciones de lo que quieres hacer podría verse así:

```js
class Amigos {

  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
    this.amigos = amigos

  }


  getAmigos() {

    var friends = []

    for (var i = 0; i < this.amigos.length; i++) {
      friends.push(this.amigos[i])
    }

    return friends
  }

}

const misAmigos = new Amigos("Francisco", 66, "Ninguno", [{
  nombre: 'martin',
  edad: 31
}, {
  nombre: 'toni',
  edad: 33
}]);

console.log(misAmigos.getAmigos());
```

Ahora supongo que quieres devolver un array totalmente nuevo y por eso no devuelves la referencia de amigos (lo cuál es más sencillo), pero es más fácil utilizar el `spread operator (...)` para generar un nuevo array, así:

```js
class Amigos {

  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
    this.amigos = amigos

  }


  getAmigos() {

    return [...this.amigos]

  }
}
const misAmigos = new Amigos("Francisco", 66, "Ninguno", [{
  nombre: 'martin',
  edad: 31
}, {
  nombre: 'toni',
  edad: 33
}]);

console.log(misAmigos.getAmigos());
```